# Outlook Add-in: Working in Web and Outlook Mac, but not on Outlook Windows. Office.js has not been fully loaded yet

Tags: office-js

I have a working Outlook Add-in that is deployed via local or URL manifest. It was developed in javascript and it's working on both Outlook Mac and any browser via Office 365.
In Windows 10 and Outlook 2016, with the same account, gives an error and shows nothing:

> Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again later or
>   make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize
>   function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: Could you share your manifest, and Outlook 2016 desktop Client build number?

Comment: Just fixed.
I realized that IE11 or Outlook in Windows still dosent support ES6 Template Strings.
Just converted to normal string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed.
I realized that IE11 or Outlook in Windows still dosent support ES6 Template Strings.
Just converted to normal string and it worked.

ex:

```
var wrong_template_string = `my long string with #{interpolation}`

var correct_string = "pre text" + other_var + "final text"
```